# How to use matplotlib from the Windows command window

Tags: python

I have written a python code in jupyter notebooks (.ipynb). I have copied the code into an editor and saved the file as .py

Now, I want to run the code from my Windows command-window. I navigate to the directory that the .py file is located within and run the code: 
`python myFile.py`

The code gets executed just the way I want to. Only one, but importat problem occurs: I am plotting a graph using matplotlib. This gets executed very fast and easily in jupyter notebooks. When I run the code on the command window, though, the graph is not plotted at all!

I have tried the following: 
I added a line `plt.ion()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

When I run this, a window is opened, but the graph isn't shown. Actually the window was still loading, when I closed it. I mean, I want to have the graph shown quickly.

I don't know what's going on or how to solve this issue. Can anyone help?

Some additional info: 
After defining all the necessary variables, this is the plotting part:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.scatter(x_D2D_TX, y_D2D_TX, s=120, color='k', label='D2D Transmitter')
plt.scatter(x_D2D_RX, y_D2D_RX, s=120, color='b', label='D2D Receiver')
plt.scatter(x_Cellular, y_Cellular, s=120, color='g', label='Cellular User')
plt.scatter(0, 0, s=120, color='r', label='Base Station')

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([-100, 100])
axes.set_ylim([-100, 100])
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('x coordinate [m]', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y coordinate [m]', fontsize=20)
plt.title('Positions of Network Nodes', fontsize=30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Was there a plt.show() after the plotting? (Asking about the non-plt.ion() version)

Comment: yep. I have added some info to my original post.

Comment: Extended that with "from matplotlib import pyplot as plt" and the line
"y_Cellular = x_Cellular = y_D2D_RX = x_D2D_RX = x_D2D_TX = y_D2D_TX = [1,2]"
and it works perfectly for me - isn't there just too much data in those variables and that's taking forever to render? But if it worked in notebook, that should not be an issue.